# How do I get a WinUI Control's parent Window?

Tags: c#, windows, winui, winui-3

I need to get a reference to the parent `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window` for a `Control`. Is there a way to do that in Project Reunion 0.5? `Window.Current` does not work in a desktop app.

Comment: Have you looked at [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getparent?view=winui-3.0)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately `Window` is not part of the visual tree.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to obtain the reference to a controls parent.
But what you could do is have a static reference to your root window in the `App` class. Then you could read this reference in your project that represents the UI layer.

**Example:**

Let's say you are using this class as top level window:

```
/// <summary>
/// An empty window that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class YourWindowClass : Window
{
    public YourWindowClass()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }   
}
```

Then you could instanciate this class in your `App` class like this (see `TopLevelWindow` property):

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{    

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }    


    public static YourWindowClass TopLevelWindow { get; } = new YourWindowClass() { Title = "Window Title..." };


    protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        TopLevelWindow.Activate();
    }
}
```

And to use the reference to the top level window, you could write this anywhere in your UI project:

```
App.TopLevelWindow
```