# How to get Main Window Handle on Page in WinUI 3 Using C++

Tags: c++, winrt-xaml, desktop-application, winui-3, c++-winrt

I am working on a WinUI 3 demo using C++.

[image]

I want to get a Main or Native Window Handler to open a `Picker` within a `Page`.

The code block which I am using works fine on `Window` but it does not work on `Page`.

```
auto windowNative{ this->try_as<::IWindowNative>()};
winrt::check_bool(windowNative);
HWND hWnd{ 0 };
windowNative->get_WindowHandle(&hWnd);
```

Help me to get `MainWindow` Handler in `Page1.xaml.cpp`

Comment: Only Window implements IWindowNative, you need to pass the window somehow or consider there's only one (depends on your application) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74273875/retrive-window-handle-in-class-library-winui3

Comment: @SimonMourier I have only one window on my app and rest are pages. Can you show how to do it using c++ ?

Comment: The C# code is actually pure interop so it's easy to translate back, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888863/how-to-get-main-window-handle-from-process-id/1888944#1888944

Comment: @SimonMourier It did not work. Can you share some code snippet or an example? I am C# developer, not c++. It will be good if you can share an easy to understand example or code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only [Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window) implements [IWindowNative](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/win32/microsoft.ui.xaml.window/nn-microsoft-ui-xaml-window-iwindownative), so you need to pass the window reference around, or if you're sure there's only one Window in your process, you can use a code like this:

```
HWND GetProcessFirstWindowHandle(DWORD pid = 0)
{
    struct ProcessWindow { DWORD pid;  HWND hWnd; } pw = {};
    pw.pid = pid ? pid : GetCurrentProcessId();
    EnumWindows([](auto hWnd, auto lParam)
        {
            DWORD pid;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pid);
            if (pid != ((ProcessWindow*)lParam)->pid)
                return TRUE;

            ((ProcessWindow*)lParam)->hWnd = hWnd;
            return FALSE;
        }, (LPARAM)&pw);
    return pw.hWnd;
}
```

And for example, call it simply like this:

```
void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    auto hwnd = GetProcessFirstWindowHandle();
}
```

You can also add some check on class name, like what's done in this answer (it's C# but the code is already using interop to access native Windows APIs) : [Retrive Window Handle in Class Library WinUI3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74286947/403671)

Comment: Hi Simon. Can you help me further with opening a file picker?  I am still facing this issue - https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2716 . Its a couple of years old bug and discussion but its not working for me either.

Comment: I raised another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75443728/fileopenpicker-returns-memory-error-in-winui3-using-c