How can I get the AppWindow for any UIElement
I'm writing an extension method for UIElement in C# Winui3.
I want to be able to get the AppWindow for any UIElement no matter if its direct parent is a page/frame or window.
Here's what I've got so far.
   public static AppWindow GetAppWindowForCurrentWindow(this UIElement element)
   {

      DependencyObject parent = element;

      while (!(parent is Window))
      {
         parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
      }


      nint hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(parent);
      WindowId myWndId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);

      return AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(myWndId);
   }

VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent) shows as null in the debugger, and gives a TypeInitializationError on the second recursion.
What should I do?

The easiest is to pass the window in a some variable or, if you're sure you only have one window, use some tooling, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74273875/retrive-window-handle-in-class-library-winui3/74286947#74286947

Yes, that's what I ended up doing during my personal implementation.  Thank you for your link, I'll look at it with fresh eyes tomorrow morning.

The WinUI 3 Gallery does something similar internally. Check this helper class. It keeps track of each Window created with this helper.
var window = WindowHelper.CreateWindow();

then:
var window = WindowHelper.GetWindowForElement(SomeButton);


